# Using the YouTube API from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, youtube-api

Is it possible to use the YouTube API from a windows service application?

All the examples I have seen look like you can only use it from a web service application.

The machine I put the windows service on will have an internet connection.

**Update: It will probably help if I get into specifics.**

Inside a windows service, I want to monitor a particular folder on a server for new video files. Once a video is dropped into a folder I want to upload the video to a YouTube playlist.

Any direction would help.

Programming Language: C#

Comment: What are you programming your Windows Service in?

Comment: I am programming my service in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's an API which is implemented as a set of [RESTful web-services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services), which you can can consume from a Windows Service. Presumably, you are talking about the [Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api), as the Player API would not make a lot of sense in an application with no user-interface!